# add x business months to a date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know how to add x business months to a datetime object with pandas? I know you can do this for business days as, e.g.:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 23) + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(20)
```

Or you can add a month as:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 23) + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)
```

But this is not giving the correct date for a business month but rather a calendar month. My definition of a business month is to exclude weekends and US Holidays for example.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a business month? i.e. what result do you want from your example?

Comment: I would like to exclude weekends and US Holidays for example

Comment: Not sure you can exclude holidays. Most likely you would have to do it by converting the business months into business days.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just realised a potential solution for 1 business month (defined as excluding weekends and US holidays) could be:

```
pd.tseries.offsets.BMonthEnd().rollforward(date) + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When the business day convention is [Following](http://help.derivativepricing.com/1514.htm):

1. Add `n` solar months, as in your example
2. Add 0 business days. This will adjust the date to match the first following business day, only in case the result of the first calculation doesn't fall on a business day.

The code above modified accordingly:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset, BDay

datetime(2017, 11, 23) + DateOffset(months=1) + BDay(0)
```

This seems to work for me. I am using pandas 0.25.1 on python 3.7.4.